# Maxscript - Animation changing vertex position in mesh

Tags: c++, animation, mesh, 3dsmax, maxscript

i have different sets of 2000 points which define the positions of the vertex of a mesh. In example, one set makes the mesh be of X form, another on Y form, etc.

I want to do an animation with this changing mesh, but Autokey fails to even place a keyframe.

My procedure is the following:

I import the mesh using the following MAXScript, which appears in 3dsmax as Object001:

```
vert_array = #()
face_array = #()
in_name = ((GetDir #export)+"/meshdata.dat")
in_file = openFile in_name
if in_file != undefined then
(
 num_verts = readValue in_file
 num_faces = readValue in_file
 vert_array.count = num_verts
 face_array.count = num_faces
 for v = 1 to num_verts do
 (
  vert = readValue in_file
  vert_array[v] = vert
 )
 for f = 1 to num_faces do
 (
  face = readValue in_file
  face_array[f] = face
 )
 close in_file
 new_mesh = mesh vertices:vert_array faces:face_array
)
```

next, I click on autokey and advance to frame 100 (for example) and execute the following MAXScript:

```
N=$Object001
animate on
(
    at time 0 (N.pos=[0,0,0] )
    at time 100 (
vert_array = #()
face_array = #()
in_name = ((GetDir #export)+"/meshdata2.dat")
in_file = openFile in_name
if in_file != undefined then
(
 num_verts = readValue in_file
 num_faces = readValue in_file
 vert_array.count = num_verts
 face_array.count = num_faces
 for v = 1 to num_verts do
 (
  vert = readValue in_file
  vert_array[v] = vert
 )
 for f = 1 to num_faces do
 (
  face = readValue in_file
  face_array[f] = face
 )
 close in_file
for v=1 to num_verts do
(
    N.verts[v].pos=vert_array[v]
)
)
)
)
```

The object manages to change its form to the desired one (although its shape doesn't change in the viewport, only when rendered).
HOWEVER, the autokey does NOT work, it does not place a keyframe on 100 nor anywhere.
It does work when changing manually the position of the vertex. But i have 2000 vertex, i need to use MAXScript.
Any clue why does this happen and how to fix it? Thank you very much indeed!

(I have tried in the Listener changin just one or two vertex, and again it doesn't work... but manually the autokey works! :'( )

Answer (score 2):

Use `meshOp.setVert` method to set the positions of the object's vertices. The changes will appear in the viewport if you use `update` when you're done:

```
N = convertToMesh (Box length:10 width:10 height:10)
with animate on at time 100 (meshOp.setVert N 1 [5,5,10])
update N
```